# After change /etc/passwd, sudo be not effect

Tags: linux, permissions, root, sudo, recovery

In my experiment, I change /etc/passwd like following.

Now the root user id be 1234, and I guess that is the reason which make all `sudo` command not effect.

I can not restore the `/etc/passwd`, because of lack writing permission.

Is there any solution ?

```
root:x:1234:1234:root:/root:/bin/bash
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

PS. This enviroment is **WSL2 archlinux**.
But I try using notepad with administrator permission, still cannot change the file.
If there is a suitable method, please also let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Normally, you'd mount the file system from a working system and then edit/fix the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it.

```
# export the distribution：
wsl --export <Distribution Name> <FileName>

# change the passwd file in the rar: /etc/passwd

# delete old distribution
wsl --unregister <Distribution Name>

# reimport the fixed distribution
wsl --import <Distribution Name> <InstallLocation> <FileName>
```